# How to handle deserialization errors in (spring) reactor-kafka

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-kafka, project-reactor

I am trying on reactor-kafka for consuming messages. I am using spring-kafka as a wrapper for reactive-kafka. I need to handle a deserialization exception - I need to send an unsuccessful message by rest (that is, it has further processing).
I wrote this solution, but it doesn't seem good to me.

Below is my consumer template and solution:

```
        reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate
                .receiveAutoAck()
                .flatMap(record -> deserialize(record)) 
                .flatMap(toy -> handle(toy))
                .subscribe();
```

convert method

```
    public Mono<Toy> deserialize(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
        return Mono.just(record)
                .map(t -> objectMapper.readValue(record.value(), Toy.class))
                .onErrorResume(e -> handleError(record.value())); //here is further processing of the deserialization exception

    }
```

I can change the deserializer to, for example

```
 props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
```

or something custom,but I do not know how to handle the deserialization error in this case

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Spring for Apache Kafaka (`spring-kafka`); `reactor-kafka` has no built-in mechanism to handle deserialization exceptions.

One solution would be to use Spring's `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` and, when the `value()` (or `key()`) is `null`, look for the deserialization exception in a header.

Since you are already using the template to wrap the reactor-kafka code, you will already have it on class path.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer

> When a deserializer fails to deserialize a message, Spring has no way to handle the problem, because it occurs before the `poll()` returns. To solve this problem, the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` has been introduced. This deserializer delegates to a real deserializer (key or value). If the delegate fails to deserialize the record content, the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` returns a `null` value and a `DeserializationException` in a header that contains the cause and the raw bytes.

Take a look at the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` to see how it uses `ListenerUtils` to extract the deserialization exception from the header(s).

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/1eaf5b3e7dac58102e1e346dd03b40ab0ff5d711/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java#L474-L477

```java
DeserializationException vDeserEx = ListenerUtils.getExceptionFromHeader(record,
        SerializationUtils.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER, this.logger);
DeserializationException kDeserEx = ListenerUtils.getExceptionFromHeader(record,
        SerializationUtils.KEY_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER, this.logger);
```

The raw data is in the `data` field of the exception, as well as a flag to indicate whether it was a key or value that failed to deserialize.